# Best solution for an StringToInt function in C#

Tags: c#

I were asked to do an StringToInt / Int.parse function on the white board in an job interview last week and did not perform very good but I came up with some sort of solution. Later when back home I made one in Visual Studion and I wonder if there are any better solution than mine below.

Have not bothred with any more error handling except checking that the string only contains digits.

```
        private int StrToInt(string tmpString)
    {
        int tmpResult = 0;

        System.Text.Encoding ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
        byte[] tmpByte = ascii.GetBytes(tmpString);

        for (int i = 0; i <= tmpString.Length-1; i++)
        {
            // Check whatever the Character is an valid digit
            if (tmpByte[i] > 47 && tmpByte[i] <= 58)
                // Here I'm using the lenght-1 of the string to set the power and multiply this to the value
                tmpResult += (tmpByte[i] - 48) * ((int)Math.Pow(10, (tmpString.Length-i)-1));
            else
                throw new Exception("Non valid character in string");

        } 

        return tmpResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your solution is reasonably ok, but instead of doing math.pow, I would do:

```
tmpResult = 10 * tmpResult + (tmpByte[i] - 48);
```

Also, check the length against the length of tmpByte rather than tmpString. Not that it normally should matter, but it is rather odd to loop over one array while checking the length of another.

And, you could replace the for loop with a foreach statement.

Comment: +1, I think I like the logic in this better than mine, because it doesn't use an extra variable (my `factor`) and loops through the string in natural order.

Answer (score 16):

I'll take a contrarian approach.

```
public int? ToInt(this string mightBeInt)
{
    int convertedInt;
    if (int.TryParse(mightBeInt, out convertedInt))
    {
        return convertedInt;
    }
    return null;
}
```

After being told that this wasn't the point of the question, I'd argue that the question tests C coding skills, not C#. I'd further argue that treating strings as arrays of characters is a very bad habit in .NET, because strings are unicode, and in any application that might be globalized, making any assumption at all about character representations will get you in trouble, sooner or later. Further, the framework already provides a conversion method, and it will be more efficient and reliable than anything a developer would toss off in such a hurry. It's always a bad idea to re-invent framework functionality.

Then I would point out that by writing an extension method, I've created a very useful extension to the string class, something that I would actually use in production code.

If that argument loses me the job, I probably wouldn't want to work there anyway.

EDIT: As a couple of people have pointed out, I missed the "out" keyword in TryParse. Fixed.

Comment: Excellent post, I wish I could upvote this twice. It's good to see people like you who think outside the box; you made several very valid points.

Comment: Personally I don't think it's a bad idea to test the basic logical/mathematical thinking skills of your candidates. Granted, they could've used a question for which there is no built-in method in the framework, but IMHO it's still a nice question. I know I had to think for a few seconds when I implemented my first `atoi` years ago (`atoi`, btw, is the C standard function for this. I don't get what you meant by your "C coding skills" quip)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the post and I like the solution. Now my task were a test to see how I would attack a problem and then not using any of the .net framework for converting the string to int.

Comment: @Matti, it is a C (and C++) practice to treat strings as character arrays and index through them. In C#, strings are not arrays, and you can't index them directly. Also, as C code goes, this is very old-school, going back to the days when standard libraries were minimal or non-existent, and developers had to write their own conversions, and when ASCII was all there was unless you were on IBM mainframes. I've actually had an interview question similar to this, but taking strings apart for textual analysis rather than conversions. I countered with the unicode argument, and didn't get the job!

Comment: why not just return null from inside of the if?

Comment: @Matti (continuing) I agree that basic coding questions are fair game for interviews, but I'd much rather see interviewers use questions that utilize .NET correctly, rather than cutting against the grain like this one does.

Comment: @Matthew, returning null works just as well. I like setting "HasValue" for readability, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: @Cylon Cat, .Net does have an indexer on a string.  You just can’t change the value because strings are immutable.

Comment: @Matthew, didn't know about the indexer. Nice to know, but I'd still use string methods and regular expressions for parsing strings.

Comment: @Cylon: Oh, and here I was thinking that you didn't want to use the indexer due to Unicode surrogate points taking up two `char`s or whatnot... meh (well, I guess you could ignore those for parsing numeric values)

Comment: @Matti, I'd expect the string indexer to return chars, but the fundamental unicode concern is that a char can be more than one byte. Converting a string to a char[] gets a different result than converting a string to a byte[]. The string class supports both conversions, but one is unicode-safe, and the other is not.

Comment: @Cylon: A C# char is not a byte, but a 16 bit integer. Still not enough to represent all the codepoints though, but luckily you can ignore those codepoints for your usual `atoi` method.

Comment: @cylon: so what kind of interview question (coding skill) would you ask?

Comment: Your answer is a good one, but the bit about globalization is nonsense.  The characters themselves are Unicode and there is no risk associated with treating a string as an array of (Unicode) chars; if there were, they wouldn't dangle a `ToCharArray` method right in front of you.  Now, converting those chars to **bytes** and passing them around as such carries a tangible risk, and you obviously need to be careful about encodings when you get down to the byte level.  But I suspect that the reason you weren't successful with the Unicode argument in your prior interview was that it's simply wrong.

Comment: +1 Your method won't actually work due to limitations concerning ref parameters, but if you fix that minor error, the idea is an natural one, which I use all the time in real projects.  Of course, that doesn't mean the ability to write little loops like this is irrelevant, even if this particular example happens to be *almost* premade in the framework.

Comment: @Aaronaught, the conversion to byte, not char, was exactly the point I was making. Obviously, extracting chars maintains Unicode integrity. Also, people who have grown up with English and ASCII tend to make unwaranted assumptions about the orderliness of character codes. Digits are relatively safe, but carrying assumptions any further is an engraved invitation for trouble.

Comment: @Cylon: If that was the point you were making then it's not particularly relevant to the question.  The OP may have come up with a flimsy solution that assumes ASCII encoding, but it's entirely possible to whiteboard this in an interview in just a few lines without any encoding issues.  There was simply no reason to bring up the subject in the context that you did, and it certainly *sounds* like you're conflating the two separate concepts of character arrays and byte arrays/byte encodings.  Oh and - by the way, your actual code still has numerous compilation errors. `Nullable<T>` is immutable.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of fixing your code example so that it compiles and does what it's supposed to - but I really think you should either clarify or remove the misleading (or at least poorly-worded) points about unicode and character arrays.

Answer (score 8):

Converting to a byte array is unnecessary, because a string is already an array of `char`s. Also, magic numbers such as `48` should be avoided in favor of readable constants such as `'0'`. Here's how I'd do it:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = str.Length - 1, factor = 1; i >= 0; i--, factor *= 10)
    result += (str[i] - '0') * factor;
```

For each character (starting from the end), add its numeric value times the correct power of 10 to the result. The power of 10 is calculated by multiplying it with 10 repeatedly, instead of unnecessarily using `Math.Pow`.

Comment: +1. The trick indeed is to iterate the characters in backwards direction.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a simple non-framework using implementation, how 'bout this:

```
"1234".Aggregate(0, (s,c)=>  c-'0'+10*s)
```

...and a note that you'd better be sure that the string consists solely of decimal digits before using this method.

Alternately, use an `int?` as the aggregate value to deal with error handling:

```
"12x34".Aggregate((int?)0, (s,c)=>  c>='0'&&c<='9' ? c-'0'+10*s : null)
```

...this time with the note that empty strings evaluate to 0, which may not be most appropriate behavior - and no range checking or negative numbers are supported; both of which aren't hard to add but require unpretty looking *wordy* code :-).

Obviously, in practice you'd just use the built-in parsing methods.  I actually use the following extension method and a bunch of nearly identical siblings in real projects:

```
public static int? ParseAsInt32(this string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) {
    int val;
    if (int.TryParse(s, style, provider, out val)) return val;
    else return null;
}
```

Though this could be expressed slightly shorter using the ternary `? :` operator doing so would mean relying on side-effects within an expression, which isn't a boon to readability in my experience.

Comment: That one almost qualify for the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest

:)

Comment: It's takes a little getting used to, but that's just what lambda's often naturally look like - and if you write your code in visual studio, it'll auto-insert human friendly spacing - a feature I absolutely adore and wish it's C++ mode would have too...

Comment: Actually, I'm still waiting for a practical IDE that'll go a step further than syntax highlighting and include inline font and style changes to better illustrate the semantics of an expression - e.g. by de-emphasizing brackets and braces that have no semantic meaning but highlighting those that affect order-of-evaluation; that enforces semantically relevant indenting, that makes compound tokens like `=>` or `==` look obviously different from their character components.

Comment: What an awesome beast. @StefanE, it's very readable for anyone who used lambda's.

Answer (score 2):

Just because i like Linq:

```
string t = "1234";
var result = t.Select((c, i) => (c - '0') * Math.Pow(10, t.Length - i - 1)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Cyclon Cat, they probably want someone who will utilize existing functionality.
But I would write the method a little bit different.

```
public int? ToInt(this string mightBeInt)
{
    int number = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(mightBeInt, out number))
        return number;
    return null;
}
```

Int32.TryParse does not allow properties to be given as out parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I was coding off the top of my head, and missed the "out" keyword, as well as property question.

Comment: I started using the .net framwork and using Int.Parse but they then told me its basically that the function they wanted me to produce. The job were with Microsoft as an test engineer and just got to know I did not got the job :)

Answer (score 1):

I was asked this question over 9000 times on interviews :) This version is capable of handling negative numbers and handles other conditions very well:

```
public static int ToInt(string s)
{
    bool isNegative = false, gotAnyDigit = false;
    int result = 0;

    foreach (var ch in s ?? "")
    {
        if(ch == '-' && !(gotAnyDigit || isNegative))
        {
            isNegative = true;
        }
        else if(char.IsDigit(ch))
        {
            result = result*10 + (ch - '0');
            gotAnyDigit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a number");
        }
    }

    if (!gotAnyDigit)
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a number");

    return isNegative ? -result : result;
}
```

and a couple of lazy tests:

```
    [TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void CommonCases()
    {
        foreach (var sample in new[]
            {
                new {e = 123, s = "123"},
                new {e = 110, s = "000110"},
                new {e = -011000, s = "-011000"},
                new {e = 0, s = "0"},
                new {e = 1, s = "1"},
                new {e = -2, s = "-2"},
                new {e = -12223, s = "-12223"},
                new {e = int.MaxValue, s = int.MaxValue.ToString()},
                new {e = int.MinValue, s = int.MinValue.ToString()}
            })
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(sample.e, Impl.ToInt(sample.s));
        }
    }
    [Test]
    public void BadCases()
    {
        var samples = new[] { "1231a", null, "", "a", "-a", "-", "12-23", "--1" };
        var errCount = 0;

        foreach (var sample in samples)
        {
            try
            {
                Impl.ToInt(sample);
            }
            catch(ArgumentException)
            {
                errCount++;
            }
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(samples.Length, errCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point! Updated so '-' is only accepted before any digit.